# CSS Grid scrolling issue: right-side padding and border "overlapping" content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't understand this behavior. Is it a bug? What do I have to do so that the right padding and border stay outside of the (orange) content?

UPDATE: I want the scrolling. The problem is that the right padding and border are not pushed to the right, but overlap the (orange) content.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<style>
*, *:before, *:after { padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; }
#grid > div { border: 20px solid orange; }
</style>
</head>
<body style='width: 90vw; height: 90vh;'>
  <div id='scrollpane' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; border: 20px solid yellow;'>
    <div id='grid' style='width: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 200px 1fr; border: 20px solid lightsteelblue; padding: 20px;'>
      <div>1fr</div><div>auto</div><div>200px</div><div>1fr</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: grid;` on the scrollpane.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
width: 90vw;
height: 90vh;
}

#scrollpane {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
border: 20px solid yellow;
display: grid; /* solution */
justify-items: stretch; /* or 'start' if you do not want content to track the scrollpane width */
align-items: start; /* or 'stretch' if you want content to track the scrollpane height */
}

#grid {
width: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 200px 1fr;
padding: 20px;
border: 20px solid lightsteelblue;
}

#grid>div {
border: 20px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='scrollpane'>
    <div id='grid'>
      <div>1fr</div>
      <div>auto</div>
      <div>200px</div>
      <div>1fr</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I observe the same issue even when I use 15% instead of 200px (but anyway, i need constant width, not percentage)

Comment: constant width will override the parent container because the parent container is defined in percentages. So, you would need to fix width 
 and min-width of the containers somewhere. Min-width means that containers cannot be smaller in width than defined. Even if width becomes smaller than min-width, min-width takes over.

Comment: I updated the question, the problem is not the scrolling, I want that. It's the padding and border on the right side that "stick", and are not pushed to the right.

Comment: Do you want the scrolling for orange box only. You can overflow:auto to div id grid and remove overflow:auto from div id scrollpane.

Comment: The scrolling is fine just like that (i want it for the yellow div with id 'scrollpane'). Look at the blue border of the content on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved with *positioning* -

1. Add `position: absolute` and `min-width: 100%` to the `#grid`.
2. Add `position: relative` to the `#scrollpane`

(When you position as `absolute` *relative* to the `scrollpane`, it is taken out of the flow and overflow behaves now.)

See demo below:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

#scrollpane {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 20px solid yellow;
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

#grid {
  position: absolute; /* ADDED */
  min-width: 100%; /* ADDED */
  /*width: 100%;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 200px 1fr;
  border: 20px solid lightsteelblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

#grid>div {
  border: 20px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='scrollpane'>
  <div id='grid'>
    <div>1fr</div>
    <div>auto</div>
    <div>200px</div>
    <div>1fr</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or better still, you can make your `scrollpane` a grid too and give `align-items: flex-start` - see demo below:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

#scrollpane {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 20px solid yellow;
  display: grid;/* ADDED */
  align-items: flex-start;/* ADDED */
}

#grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 200px 1fr;
  border: 20px solid lightsteelblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

#grid>div {
  border: 20px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='scrollpane'>
  <div id='grid'>
    <div>1fr</div>
    <div>auto</div>
    <div>200px</div>
    <div>1fr</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed! You sure know your CSS! Now there are 2 solutions that work. I really don't understand these position instructions, do you care to elaborate?

Comment: when you position as `absolute`, it is taken out of the flow and `overflow` behaves now... adding `display: grid` to `scrollpane` also works I guess...

Comment: I guess setting the scrollpane to grid somehow amounts to the same as what you did. But why is the relative position on the scrollpane needed?

Comment: because if not specified, `absolute` positioning will be based on the `body` element.... meanwhile, updated answer

Comment: To be fair I think that is the same solution as Amit provided. When I tested his answer I already used `align-items: start;`. I think it would be better to leave your answer to showcase your original solution.

Comment: I like Amit's answer because it is shorter, but also more magic. I like yours because it made me understand the issue better.

Comment: Ohh, these *inline styles*! you can mark Amit's answer as correct :)